# Не работает обновление записи в БД (Linq to SQL)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq2sql

Пытаюсь разобраться, почему не обновляться запись. Создавать новую и удалять получается, а обновлять нет.

Так выглядит функция Апдейт:

```
public bool UpdateNote(Notes instance)
{
    Notes cache = Db.Notes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == instance.ID);
    if (cache != null)
    {
        cache.Content = instance.Content;
        cache.AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
        Db.Notes.Context.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Код NotesView:

```
public class NotesView
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название заметки")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Маппер для связи Model-ModelView:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Notes, NotesView>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserID));

            Mapper.CreateMap<NotesView, Notes>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId));
```

ну и вызов функции апдейт в контроллере:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(NotesView notesView)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userEmail = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Email"].Value);

        var user = Repository.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Email == userEmail);
        notesView.UserId = user.ID;

        var note = (Notes)ModelMapper.Map(notesView, typeof(NotesView), typeof(Notes));

        Repository.UpdateNote(note);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(notesView);
}
```

Подобным образом делались добавления новых записей и их удаления, с ними проблем нет, все работает хорошо, а вот обновление не пашет.

Пробовал ставить точку останова на методе, который вносит данные в БД, но до нее так и не дошло. По все видимости из клиентской части не входит в контроллер.

Для более полной картинки выкладываю еще и клиентский код.
Код вьюшки:

```
@model Proj.Models.ViewModels.NotesView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Редактор заметок";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Default/Views/Shared/NotesLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="ui stackable grid two column">
    <div class="two wide column"></div>
    <div class="ten wide column">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Notes", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()

            <div class="inline field">
                <label>Название заметки: </label>
                <div class="ui fluid icon input">
                  @Html.TextBox("EditName", Model.Name, new { @readonly="readonly" })
                  <i class="tag icon"></i>
                </div>        
            </div>
            <br />

            <div class="inline field">
                <div class="ui fluid icon input">
                  @Html.TextArea("EditEditor", Model.Content)
                </div>        
            </div>

            <br />    
            <div class="inline field">
                <input type="button" value="Сохранить" class="ui blue button" id="EditNotes"/>
                @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index", "Notes", null, new { @class = "ui green button"})
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

И код Ajax - запроса:

```
$("#EditNotes").click(function () {

        //alert(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Notes/Edit",
            data: { Content: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() }
        }).done(function () {
            document.location.href = "/Notes";
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
    });
```

Помогите разобраться.

**Обновление**

Прошелся отладчиком, по добовлению, там все ок, а вот на редактировании - если я правильно понимаю, то даже не вошел в метод Edit в контролере. Ок, тогда проблема с Ajax запросом. Код Ajaxa:

```
 $("#EditNotes").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Notes/Edit",
        data: { Content: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() }
    }).done(function () {
        document.location.href = "/Notes";
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
});
```

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Возьмите отладчик и пройдитесь по шагам.

Comment: Хотя у метода Add точно такой же Ajax запрос. И там все работает. Что же не так тут?

Comment: отредактируйте текст вопроса (уберите серверный код, если он ни причем). добавьте туда клиентский под. ну и опять же - попробуйте отладить в браузере. и посмотрите консоль и таб network на наличие ошибок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В модель нужно добавить идентификатор записи.

```
public class NotesView
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    //... 
}
```

Добавьте к разметке формы редактирования заметки идентификатор.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Notes", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "" }))
    {
      <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="Model.ID" />
    }
```

Comment: Во, а это то что нужно, спасибо.

Comment: Отметьте, пожалуйста, как ответ =)

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы форма отправляла данные на сервер Вам стоит заменить строку в блоке кода который отрисовывает кнопку внизу формы. В Вашем случае там указан неверный type

```
<input type="button" value="Сохранить" class="ui blue button" id="EditNotes"/>
```

На

```
<input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="ui blue button" id="EditNotes"/>
```

Comment: Проблема была не в этом. Тут не имеет значения тип кнопки, так как используется Ajax запрос привязанный к ИД кнопки. Проблема была в том, что в метод апдейт приход нулевое значение ИД.